# Applying for a tourist UK visa without salary slips - I'm a freelancer. What can I use as proof of funds?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-funds

I want to apply for UK visa for a holiday. I am a freelancer working for 2 companies where I take up projects. Depending on the projects I am then paid.

I do not have the usual monthly salary slips. I am directly paid into my account after my project ends. For 1 company I take up monthly projects and the other is 2-3 times a year.

Will there be a problem in getting the visa because I don't have monthly salary slips?

Comment: Depending on your country of citizenship, you may or may not need a visa at all if you are going for a short period of time.

Comment: For you salary part, explain it in your application(if you need a visa). You would be billing the clients, don't you have the bills from them. The amount in the bills should corroborate the deposits in your bank accounts. Or ask the clients to issue you a letter mentioning the payments made to you.

Comment: Tax returns can be helpful in some cases like these, but not all.  What is your nationality and how is your bank account denominated?

Answer (score 1):

It won't be a problem as I used to do that (at least in my case). They usually look at your bank statement and they want to see the movements of the transactions. I used to have only my bank statement to apply for the visa and they asked me what do I do for a living. I said I was unemployed and I wanted to visit my friend and I intended to return to my home country at this date. If they don't trust you that the amount of money you have is going to be enough they usually ask for more documents and you can supply more supporting documents as needed.